# no such element exception

Tags: java

### Descripción

Los números en su representación binaria están formados por unos y ceros. Se quiere conocer cuantas pares de unos seguidos existen en en un número. Por ejemplo el numero 710 en binario es 1112 y existe un par de unos. El numero 310 en binario es 112 tiene una pareja de unos. El numero 1510 en binario es 11112 y tiene dos pares de unos. El numero 1010 en binario es 10102 no tiene pares de unos.

Dado un numero decimal menor a 225 contar cuantos pares de unos existen en su representación binaria.

### Entrada

La entrada consiste de varios casos de prueba, la primera linea contiene un numero que indica el número de casos de prueba. Cada caso de prueba consiste en un numero decimal menor a 225.

### Salida

Escriba en la salida el numero de pares de unos que tiene el numero.

**Ejemplo Entrada**

> ```
> 5
> 3
> 10
> 15
> 20
> 255
> ```

**Ejemplo Salida**

> ```
> 1
> 0
> 2
> 0
> 4
> ```

---

Mi código es este:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejercPares {

    public static void imprimeEscalera(int M) {
        int exp, digito;
        double binario;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
        } while (M < 0);
        exp = 0;
        binario = 0;
        while (M != 0) {
            digito = M % 2;
            binario = binario + digito * Math.pow(10, exp);
            exp++;
            M = M / 2;
        }
        int co = 0;
        int co2 = 0;
        int co3 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            co = (int) (binario % 10);

            if (binario == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (co == 1) {
                co2++;
            }
            co3 = (int) (binario / 10);
            binario = co3;
        }
        System.out.println(co2 / 2);
        co2 = co2 * 0;
        binario = binario * 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N;
        Scanner lee = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (lee.hasNext()) {
            N = lee.nextInt();
            int j = 0;
            while (j <= N) {
                j++;
                int M = lee.nextInt();
                imprimeEscalera(M);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al enviar al juez me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu main, si N son los casos de prueba y `int j=0;` entonces `while(j<=N)` deberia ser `< N` de otra forma estas leyendo N+1 casos

Comment: Es bastante raro ese enunciado, los numeos en binario justamente tiene unos y ceros, pero luego dices que el numero 710 en binario es 1112 el cual contiene un 2, eso no es correcto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta la parte de tu enunciado:

> Dado un numero decimal menor a 225 contar cuantos pares de unos
>   existen en su representación binaria

Te dejo un script con algunos casos de prueba a método descriptivo que calcula primero la representación binaria del numero decimal y luego calcula la cantidad de repeticiones de "11" en esa representación binaria, deberás adaptarlo a tu código:

```
int []casosDePrueba = {3,5,10,15,20,255};
String binario;

for(int caso:casosDePrueba){
    binario = Integer.toBinaryString(caso);//calculo la representacion binaria
    System.out.println(caso+" en binario es: "+binario);

    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while((index = binario.indexOf("11", index)) != -1){
        index += 2;//corro dos espacios por el length de "11" para la nueva busqueda
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("repeticiones de '11' encontradas:"+count);
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
}
```

Adicionalmente dejo un [sandbox](http://tpcg.io/ujuGiO) para que puedas verlo en funcionamiento

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo

Comment: @DALM10 me alegro que te haya servido, deberías entonces marcar la respuesta como correcta para que así pueda servirle a los demás, puedes hacerlo con el tilde que esta arriba a la izquierda de la misma. saludos!